# Add "webapps.stackexchange.com" as a destination in the "Vote to Close as Off-Topic" dialog

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration, vote-to-close, close-reasons

As an active participant in the facebook.stackoverflow.com mini-site, most of the off-topic questions are coming from frustrated end users looking for support on the web app. I've also seen this on the main SO site.

I see several of these questions per day. It would be nice to have the option to have this question transitioned over to a site where they might be able to get a solution.

Comment: Are they actual questions about using Facebook or stuff like "why can't I log in"/"why is my account blocked"/"why can't I pay for farmville"? None of the latter kind would be on-topic on WebApps.

Comment: @AnnaLear: "Why won't Stack Exchange employees accept my friend requests??"

Comment: No. I agree those questions (and users) should just go away. This is the question that prompted this request. http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14488382/facebook-events-in-news-feed

Comment: @cpilko For a one-off fitting question like that, just flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be migrated. There's no need to bump a site that actually gets frequent community-driven migrations from the migration destinations list to slot webapps in.

Comment: Don't you dare.

Comment: But @ChrisF, you're a facebook power user (diamond on WebApps QED) and we'd like to put these wonderful questions in your capable hands ;)

Comment: @sixlettervariables - I really, really hope you are joking.

Comment: Down votes registered. I removed my hating on TeX.

Comment: Your hating on TeX isn't the main problem here, suggesting that crap questions should be moved to another SE site instead of closed on sight is.

Comment: Migration doesn't mean "I don't this here". It means "X wants this"

Comment: @Yannis: No. Crap questions should die. All I'm saying is there should be a path for quality questions to be migrated.

Comment: Then, the answer is simple: Flag those quality questions and ask for them to be moved. If WebApps makes it into the top 4 of migration targets, it will be added to the migration target list.

Comment: @Yannis Fair enough.

Comment: @Yannis - I would hope (and expect) that they'd only add Web Apps (or any site) as a migration target if that site wanted to be a target.

Comment: @ChrisF In theory, I'd hope and expect the same. In practice, I didn't care at all about TeX making it into the list (as it replaced ProgSE).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the past 90 days there have been 3 questions migrated from SO to webapps with a 66% rejection rate, which means there has been exactly **one** appropriate migration in the past 90 days.  There are 26 more SE sites that have more migrations (from SO) than webapps.

So no, it's not a good candidate for the frequent migration targets.

Comment: But if we increased the quantity of migrations, surely the quality would improve too!

Comment: @mmyers Yep, just ask server fault about that.

Comment: Thanks for the data-based answer @Servy.